# Trying to calculate average but I get the error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java

I am trying to create a function to calculate an average, but I keep getting an error message, which is really frustrating because I know it is a super easy function. I keep getting the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException so I know it has something to do with an index error but I can't figure it out.

```
public int berekenGemiddeldeScore(){

    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (deelnemers.size() == 1){

        return deelnemers.get(1).getScore();
    }

    while (i< deelnemers.size() -1 ){

        result+=deelnemers.get(i).getScore();
        i++;
    }

    return result/deelnemers.size();

}
```

Comment: Any piece of code that you could paste...

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Yeah sorry lol I accidently entered before I finished my question.

Comment: ```if (deelnemers.size() == 1){

        return deelnemers.get(1).getScore();
    }```

if that condition is met... the only index should be... 0 right, not 1?

Comment: Woops yes, I don't know why I put 1 there.

Comment: If size is 1, index should be 0. counting starts at 0, 1, 2...N-1 where n is the size.

Comment: @RandomStacker what is the type of `deelneimers`? Is it List<?>?

Comment: Whoops, the dupe is about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, but they're pretty much the same thing.

Comment: It's an ArrayList.

Comment: @RandomStacker I updated my answer. there is no reason to have special case when the list has size 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Java and many other languages the first index is `0`, not `1`. In your case the collection has size 1, so the only index you can access using `get` is `0`: `deelnemers.get(0)`.

If you try to access using an index that does not exist in the collection, an exception of type `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this-

```
public int berekenGemiddeldeScore(){

int result = 0;
int i = 0;

if (deelnemers.size() == 1){
    return deelnemers.get(0).getScore();
}

while (i < deelnemers.size()){

    result+=deelnemers.get(i).getScore();
    i++;
}

return result/deelnemers.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with only one item, "`if (deelnemers.size() == 1)`" the index of your array is 0:

`return deelnemers.get(0).getScore();`

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue

```
if (deelnemers.size() == 1) {
    return deelnemers.get(1).getScore();
}
```

Replace return statement with

```
 return deelnemers.get(0).getScore();
```

---

Edit

There is no reason for a special case if list size is one. 
Think about this approach

```
public int berekenGemiddeldeScore() {
    if (deelnemers.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (Score score : deelnemers) {
        result += score.getScore();
    }

    return result / deelnemers.size();
}
```